# How to remove class clicking inner div

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I have two divs. When one is clicked, it opens and the other closes. I want to be able to close the div that is currently open by either clicking the other div or by clicking a "[x]". I've got the first part working correctly, but the current div only toggles classes instead of closing after clicking the "[x]".

```
$("main-element .close").click(function() {

        if( $('.main-element').hasClass("open") ) {
            $('.main-element').removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
        } 
});


$(".main-element").click(function() {

        if( $(this).hasClass("open") ) {
            $(this).removeClass("open").addClass("closed");
        } else {
            $(this).siblings().removeClass("open").addClass("closed"); 
            $(this).removeClass("closed").addClass("open");
        }

});
```

I've added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mcnutty757/kuYRh/50/) to help explain it a little better.

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly.... Your code is working...?

Comment: Sorry for the poor explanation. When I click inside the div (text, etc.) -I don't want it to close. I only want it to close when the yellow [x] is clicked or when the other closed div is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Here try this code : http://jsfiddle.net/kuYRh/56/

The key is the `e.stopPropagation()` since the [x] is in the `div`

Answer (score 0):

How about a toggleClass approach? The only thing I can tell that this doesn't accomplish, is the fact that you can still close the box by clicking the image. (not the .main-element background - but the image) ~ which I like anyways.This simplifies things quite a bit. This is the code assuming you gut out all of the other jQuery and remove any classes that are no longer needed from the CSS.

jQuery

```
$(".main-element img, .close").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.main-element').toggleClass("open");
});
```

CSS

```
.main-element {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.open   {
  height:440px;
  width:440px;
}
```

Comment: I bet there is a happy marriage between this code and Karl-André Gagnon' code -